# Javascript global bools behaving weird in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wanted to add a feature to my WebGL application, that allows me to switch the size of the canvas WebGL is rendering to. I just have a simple boolean that indicates in which state it should be and observed a weird behavior in Firefox.

So I have a global bool `var fullScreen = false;` and a event listener function that roughly looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) =>  {
    if(e.which == 89) {
        fullScreen = !fullScreen;

        /* Adjusting the canvases size */
    }
});
```

So every time I press the `y` key the variable `fullscreen` should be set to its opposite and that  works perfectly in Safari and Chrome.

In Firefox however the variable stays at true no matter how many times I press the key. If `fullscreen` is a local variable (I have my event listener in an other function) everything works normal.

Is this intended behavior and Chrome and Safari just allow it or is this a bug in Firefox? Is there a way to fix this, keeping this variable global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't have support for .which, in fact, it's deprecated, so you should start using e.key

```
if(e.which == 89) {
```

to

```
if(e.key == 89) { // didn't confirm this is the right keycode, so you may need to change it, but it should work
```

EDIT:
Ah, investigating the problem, I was able to reproduce it. I fixed it, however, by using let instead of var. Not sure why, but FF handles var oddly, but let will do the same thing :)

Deprecation source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: Thanks for that, I though it was the other way around that .which is the new style. But anyways I get an event that the key is pressed, so this can't be the problem

Comment: Sorry about that, answer updated! Its a "var" vs "let" situation it seems